# Compiling custom Bootstrap css in yii2 from less

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, composer-php, yii2

I'm starting a new project in Yii2 and Composer (after a few projects with YII 1).

I created a new "advanced project" with composer. Everything is okay but, I'm wondering what is the best way to customize the bootstrap theme?

I think copying the whole bootstrap less to the backend and to the frontend and edit the two variables file and compile it isn't the right way.

So: is it somehow possible to extend the less files downloaded by the composer and edit only the two variables file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap configuration can be done by changing variables.less.
The following BootstrapAsset is the replacement of original one, that uses bootstrap-variables.less in current directory instead of original variables.less.

```
namespace app\assets;

use yii\helpers\FileHelper;
use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class BootstrapAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = '@bower/bootstrap/dist';
    public $css = [
        'css/bootstrap.css',
    ];

    public function publish($am)
    {
        if ($this->sourcePath !== null && !isset($this->basePath, $this->baseUrl)) {
            list ($this->basePath, $this->baseUrl) = $am->publish($this->sourcePath, $this->publishOptions);
        }

        $src = \Yii::getAlias($this->sourcePath);

        FileHelper::copyDirectory("$src/../less", $this->basePath."/less");

        $vars = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . "/bootstrap-variables.less");
        $css = \Yii::$app->cache->get("bootstrap-css-".crc32($vars));
        if (!$css)
        {
            file_put_contents("$src/../less/variables.less", $vars);

            ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 200);

            $less = new \lessc();
            $less->setFormatter(YII_DEBUG ? "lessjs" : "compressed");
            unlink($this->basePath . "/css/bootstrap.css");
            $less->compileFile("$src/../less/bootstrap.less", $this->basePath . "/css/bootstrap.css");
            \Yii::$app->cache->set("bootstrap-css-".crc32($vars), file_get_contents($this->basePath . "/css/bootstrap.css"));
        }
        else
        {
            file_put_contents($this->basePath . "/css/bootstrap.css", $css);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you replace the original one? You just put your code into `assets/BootstrapAsset.php`?

Comment: Found out that you do put it into the `assets` folder, then you add `BootstrapAsset::register($this);` to your layout in `views/layouts/main.php`. But then I have the problem that the class `lessc` is not available so I can't use it afterall...

Comment: You can have lessc by including dependency to oyejorge/less.php in your composer.json

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the question. Why do you not create a custom.css or custom.less file that you load last and just overwrite what you need? Another solution would be to extend the less file http://css-tricks.com/the-extend-concept/ and use the extended file instead of the normal one.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the basic app.

To change some Bootstrap properties (field height for example) I did the following:

1. Create a new css-file with changed properties: **web\css\bootstrap-modified.css**
2. Add this file to **assets\AppAssets.php:**

> ```
> public $css = [
>     'css/site.css',
>     'css/bootstrap-modified.css'
> ];
> ```

Comment: Good for simple changes, bad for complex changes where you really should recompile from LESS. (and most customizations eventually turn into complex changes before you are finally done)

Answer (score 0):

```
In basic app..(yii2)../.    

First create your css in (in website folder)Basic->web->css->custom.css(Your CSS File)

After that if we want add new css to our site, go to (in website folder)Basic->assets and open              AppAsset.php.
and add 'custom.css' after 'css/site.css' like below.  
 -------------------------------------------------------     

<?php
namespace app\assets;
use yii\web\AssetBundle;
/**
 * @author Qiang Xue <qiang.xue@gmail.com>
 * @since 2.0
 */
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
        'css/custom.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];

 --------------------------------------------------------------------

You can add it in your page by 

use app\basic\web\css;
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to include another copy of Bootstrap, I wanted to customize it. So the answer is to load your customized copy of Bootstrap instead the base bootstrap.

A good tutorial is found [here](http://webtips.krajee.com/override-bootstrap-css-js-yii-2-0-widgets/)