# Yii2, how to use bootstrap less in yii2 project?

Tags: yii2

I want to use bootstrap less variable in my less file.

example)

```
.masthead {
  background-color: @brand-primary;
}
```

Just using

```
public $depends = [
    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
];
```

and If I compile it using winless, I got an error the @brand-primary is not defined.

I think I need to import bootstrap.less file, is there any extension for it or any tutorial from scratch?

please advise me,

Comment: refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27045361/compiling-custom-bootstrap-css-in-yii2-from-less

Comment: Hi Skull, that link is for custom bootstrap css, I need bootstrap.less (libarary) file and import that into my less file so that I can use bootstrap library in my less file like variables. So my question is how can I have the bootstrap.less in my less file in yii2 project, I have bootstrap which I got by composer `"yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "2.0.*@dev",`

Comment: See http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#asset-conversion